# Alert on click using JQuery for Id loaded using JQuery

Tags: jquery, click, onload

When the user clicks div having id ***minus_1_36*** also shown in the image, it should alert ***hi***. But it doesn't alert. There is no error in the console.

[image]

#### new_invoice_table.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="http://localhost/project/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/project/fontawesome/fontawesome/css/all.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="siteloader"></div>​
  <script src="http://localhost/project/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/project/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/project/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script>
    function get_table() {
      $("#siteloader").load('new_invoice_table_ajax.php')
    }
    $('#minus_1_36').click(function() {
      alert("hi");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### new_invoice_table_ajax.php:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Service Name</td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
      <div id="minus_1_36" class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-3x"></div><span>3</span>
      <a href="" class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-3x"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you append any element after DOM has loaded, you can use `delegate()` selector `$("body").delegate("#minus_1_36", "click", function(){})` Because table loads with `load()` after page has loaded.

```
function get_table() {
  $("#siteloader").load('new_invoice_table_ajax.php')
}
$("body").delegate('#minus_1_36', 'click',function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

You can look all of details delegate() selector in [this URL](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

***You should load your script after the DOM has loaded***

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="http://localhost/project/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/project/fontawesome/fontawesome/css/all.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="siteloader"></div>​
  <div id="minus_1_36">
  click me
  </div>
  <script>
    function get_table() {
      $("#siteloader").load('new_invoice_table_ajax.php')
    }
    $('#minus_1_36').click(function() {
      alert("hi");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Or you can use the below jquery code anywhere in your html file inside a script***

```
$(document).on("click","#minus_1_36",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: `<div id="minus_1_36">
  click me
  </div>` this should be on another page, not on the same page!

Comment: put the js code in an external script and include the script tag with path to your src in the new_invoice_table_ajax.php file. rest all the same. Include your script tag after the DOM or use $(document).on() method in your script and load the script anywhere in you new_invoice_table_ajax.php file.

Answer (score 0):

If we put `click()` in the ***new_invoice_table_ajax.php***, it works!:

#### new_invoice_table.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="http://localhost/project/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/project/fontawesome/fontawesome/css/all.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="siteloader"></div>​
  <script src="http://localhost/project/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/project/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/project/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script>
    function get_table() {
      $("#siteloader").load('new_invoice_table_ajax.php')
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### new_invoice_table_ajax.php:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Service Name</td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
      <div id="minus_1_36" class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-3x"></div><span>3</span>
      <a href="" class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-3x"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $('#minus_1_36').click(function() {
      alert("hi");
    });
  </script>
```